# kdiff3 : Auto save and quit on merge without conflits don't work

Tags: merge, directory, kdiff3

I try to merge 2 directories with some differents files with kdiff3.

Unfortunaly, when I start directory merge, it stop at each file, even there are no conflits, and I need to restart it.

I check the option "Auto save and quit on merge without conflits" in settings, but no difference.

Do I do something wrong ?

Comment: Is this using kdiff3 standalone (e.g. you start kdiff3 with two directory arguments) or using kdiff3 as an associated mergetool in a version control system (e.g. git)?

Comment: I used it standalone, but I finaly used Meld, it work better.